# Macbook Pro file mods

Tags: macbook-pro, folders

When I run `ls -l` there are files listed with `@` file mod for some folders:

```
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  admin      170 Sep  4 13:51 Users
drwxrwxrwt@  3 root  admin      102 Sep  5 09:02 Volumes
```

I realized that the folders with `@` sign can not be displayed in Finder.
Can somebody tell me what is the `@` sign for and how i can remove it?

Answer (score 0):

The `@` sign means that the files have extended attributes. What you noticed was the extended attribute `com.apple.FinderInfo`, which can be modified to have Finder hide the file.

Using `ls -@`, you can see the extended attributes of the file.

This is what shows up when I run `ls -dl@ Library` when my Library folder is hidden:

```
drwx------@ 54 me  staff  1836 Aug 31 11:16 Library
     com.apple.FinderInfo   32
```

and when it is showing (a setting in Show View Options in Finder on your home directory):

```
drwx------+ 54 me  staff  1836 Aug 31 11:16 Library
```

The `com.apple.FinderInfo   32`  means that the file is hidden. (32 is just the bit  they chose to represent it, `1<<5`. This is called a [bitmask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)).)

You can hide and show files with `chflags hidden` and `chflags nohidden`, enabling and disabling that bit of `com.apple.FinderInfo`.